# Javascript: slice and substring not working as expected

Tags: javascript, string

I expect to give me 4 characters from second position. but doesn't.

```
<body id = "A">
<script>
var s = document.getElementById("A");
var d = "Hello, world";
s.innerHTML = d.substring(2,4);
</script>
```

It work when:

```
d.substring(0,4);
```

Comment: You probably want `substr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments for `substring` are start and end, not start and length.

```
string.substring(start,end)
Parameter Values
Parameter   Description
start   Required. The position where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0
end     Optional. The position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string
```

There is an addition function `substr` that has arguments of start and length

```
string.substr(start,length)
Parameter Values
Parameter   Description
start   Required. The position where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0
length  Optional. The number of characters to extract. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string
```

You can [see more at "W3Schools" here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) .. you may find this a useful reference for other issues you encounter.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
var s = document.getElementById("A");
var d = "Hello, world";
s.innerHTML = d.trim().substr(2,4);
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7g3ep/1/)

[`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) are different methods!